# Maps API autocomplete suggestion won't replace value of input

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an input field that uses Google Maps API autocomplete. I want to save the data from that input to database(Firebase). But the issue is that after selecting the autocomplete result and submitting the form it shows the value saving what **I typed prior to selecting autocomple**

EX:

I select "New York City..." from autocomplete after typing "New"
Even though the input field shows "New York City" what it submits is only "New"

For demo purposes I hooked it up to a Google Map iframe: Full code found here: http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/wJyXKR?editors=1111

```
const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(searchInput);

searchInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
    let addr = searchInput.value;
    console.log(addr)
    let embed= "<iframe frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='https://maps.google.com/maps?&amp;q="+ encodeURIComponent( addr ) + "&amp;output=embed'></iframe>";  

    $('.place').html(embed);                                         
});
function getInput(){

    var addr = document.getElementById('searchTextField').value;


        var embed= "<iframe frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='https://maps.google.com/maps?&amp;q="+ encodeURIComponent( addr ) + "&amp;output=embed'></iframe>";  

        $('.place').html(embed);

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello_ mate,

it seems like `searchInput.value` is still not updated when you call your code.

Try putting a timeout before executing your code - see forked codepen **[HERE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VqdxVX?editors=1111)**

So you can fix your issue like this:

```
searchInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
    // Wrap in setTimeout, so you give time searchInput.value to be updated
    setTimeout(function() {
        let addr = searchInput.value;
        console.log(addr)
        let embed = "<iframe frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='https://maps.google.com/maps?&amp;q=" + encodeURIComponent(addr) + "&amp;output=embed'></iframe>";

        $('.place').html(embed);
    }, 100); 
});
```

**Conclusion**

There is a delay before `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` updates the value of `<input>`

Comment: Places Autocomplete API provides a way to get the selected address, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete